# module property in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

As per my understanding we can assign value "commonjs" or "AMD"
to "module" property in tsconfig.json.

Can we assign any other value other than these two.

```
....
....
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
 }
}
....
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can, allowed values are:

> "commonjs", "amd", "umd", "system", "es6", "es2015", "none".

Directly from [json schema](http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig)

Or in more readable format see `--module` in [compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)